# Real life application of two-way DFA

Tags: automata-theory, dfa, finite

I am currently studying two-way DFA and I couldn't find and research anything on its real-life applications if there are any. I am very unsure where it could be used and any ideas would be great. tyia

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? As a computational model, they are exponentially more succinct than their 1-way counterparts, so they allow easy modelling. Also, techniques that were developed for them, e.g., crossing-sequences, have proven useful in other models, e.g. string-to-string transducers. Is this what you consider "real life"?

Comment: Not directly related, but you can check multi-pass streaming algorithms.